# Combo box not allowing me to write and select a value

Tags: c#, selenium

I have few combo style boxes to automate.Like those ones in which you write a few characters,enter, it then opens a drop down list with relevant matches, and you select one of them.(Please correct me if they are not called combo)

Select Element doesn't work as it gives error because I have to type a few words in it, and it says the value was entered rather than selected. I tried Send Keys, Sleep, Key down, Enter. It worked for me for few times, but fails with Time out error mostly. Though i have tried increasing time.

```
          driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[2]/div/form/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div/input")).SendKeys("L");
          driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[2]/div/form/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div/input")).Click();
          new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy((By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]"))));
          new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy((By.XPath("//*[@id='sug-0']"))));
          driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='sug-0']")).Click();
```

I am not even sure if this is efficient way to work with these sort of controls. Anyone got any ideas on it? Cheers!

Error message i get is: **Test method threw exception: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds**

Edited: this is html after typing in the box. It has no list controls, just few hundred divs like this

```
<div class="Suggestions-container sugCon" id="sug-list-id__20" role="listbox">
<div id="sug-0" aria-selected="true" role="option">
<div id="sug-1" aria-selected="false" role="option">
<div id="sug-2" aria-selected="false" role="option"> .....
```

Comment: Can you send the url?

Comment: sorry, thats not hosted publicly :( its more like an editable drop downlist

Comment: Post the relevant html and error message.

Comment: after typing there should be a <UL> and some <LI> tags under that with some options.  You want to target the <LI>'s to click on them.  If there is a specific option you want target use the LI's contents with XPATH's "text()" function.   Try editing your question to include the full HTML after typing.

Comment: Thanks, edited now. no UL or LI, just some divs in there.